# Database design recommendation for [object] - [role] - [user] relationship, and potential performance implications of two approaches

Tags: database-design

Wanted to get some community input on an application my team recently inherited.  Overall the application has a myriad of SELECT performance issues - The main one I want to focus on right now relates to a table with approximately 20 columns that represent different roles (Admin, Contributor 1, Contributor 2, General Contact, etc)  for a particular row in that table.  Each row in the table represents an object, and the [role] columns indicate which user has that role for the object.  Each role column has a foreign key relationship to the [user] table.

When the application needs to display user information related to the roles for this table, the SELECT statements have to join to the [user] table 20 different times, once for each column.

```
SELECT role1.user_name, role2.user_name, role3.user_name, ...
FROM [object] AS o
LEFT JOIN [user] AS role1 ON o.role_1_user_id = role1.id
LEFT JOIN [user] AS role2 ON o.role_2_user_id = role2.id
LEFT JOIN [user] AS role3 ON o.role_3_user_id = role3.id
...
```

My gut tells me we could probably get better performance redesigning the table to remove the role columns, and adding a join table containing object_id, role_id and user_id columns.  I would potentially need to pivot the data to see it in a similar format for reports, but I think the overall performance would be better in other cases.

Would love to hear advice on the design options, and any other approaches that I may be missing.

Comment: It is a *Multicolumn Attribute* Antipattern. You are on right track.

Comment: Indeed, a link table would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, another benefit of the link table approach is that we can enforce unique constraints in the db (user can only be assigned 1 role for an object, etc) that we cannot enforce using the db currently.